# Cordova OneSignal Sdk not working in React Capacitor Project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cordova, capacitor

I'm getting this error

> TypeError: window.OneSignal.push is not a function

in the latest SDK and Cordova plugin. But when I downgraded the `onesignal-cordova-plugin` to `2.11.3` I get a plugin_not_installed error.

```
import React from "react";
import { OneSignal } from "@awesome-cordova-plugins/onesignal";

React.useEffect(()=> {
  OneSignalInit();
}, [])

  const OneSignalInit = async () => {

    OneSignal.startInit(import.meta.env.VITE_ONESIGNAL_APPID, import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID); // Error: TypeError: window.OneSignal.push is not a function

  };
```

Package JSON:

[image: OneSignal Plugin Version in my Package.json]